# Questions about the ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

i have a problem with android studio and i hope you can help me. I am developing my first app for android only that I am making some confusion with the layouts, in my project all the xml files are ConstraintLayout and I have inserted all the anchors, only that if I open the app with a larger device the layout turns out wrong. How can I do? I thought of varying width and height according to the size of the screen through the activity class but I don't know if it is correct to use the LayoutParams and even less which parameters to pass as it does not accept int, thank you very much.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();

    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;
    b1.setLayoutParams();
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="609dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/posate"
        android:contentDescription="Ristoranti"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/visitare"
        android:contentDescription="Posti da visitare"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/regole"
        android:contentDescription="Regolamento"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/escursioni"
        android:contentDescription="Escursioni"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/posti"
        android:contentDescription="Posti vicini"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/contatti"
        android:contentDescription="Contatti"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:text="Restaurant"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/b1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/b1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="84dp"
        android:text="Place to visit"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/b"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/b"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Regulation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/b2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.444"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/b2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Nearby places"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/b4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.64"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/b4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="95dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"
        android:text="Contacts"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/b5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.479"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/b5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/b5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="84dp"
        android:text="Excursion"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/b3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.479"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/b3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b3" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Also in Studio 4.0 there is the Layout Validator which provides a quick glimpse of your layout in many screen sizes (without having to deploy to each emulator/device).

Comment: Hi @Giovanni use wrap_content , match_parent and weights to make your UI responsive , use hardcoded values for margin padding only and if my answer helped please upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t have to use LayoutParams, In android you need to avoid hard coded values and rely upon ratios , weights and relative positions to make a layout responsive. your anchors mights be relaying on hardcoded values in XML please share your XML code that would help ,

Also try going through the official docs that would help

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout